# SQL Server login account (SQLExecutiveCMDExec) getting locked

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, Checking the server (Server2) is available using OSQL command from Server1. When Server2 is unavailable then the below query will run multiple times. If Server2 is taking more time to reboot then below query locks out the SQL Server login account which is SQLExecutiveCMDExec. So Server2 is down since SQL Server login account is locked so SQL Server service is unable to start.

```
SELECT  @Exec_String = 'osql /S ' + @ServerName + ' /U '+ @UserName + ' /P '+ @Pwd
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Exec_String
```

Have tried using linked server query to check the availability of the server but facing same issue when server takes more time to reboot.

Please help me, is there any other way to check the availability of the server without locking the SQL Server login account when try multiple times.

Comment: Please **stop using** `osql` - it's beyond dead. Use `sqlcmd` instead.

Comment: @marc_s , I know `osql` is deprecated. changing to `sqlcmd` will not resolve my issue